# MongoDB: How to query between two hours?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection of restaurants that I would like to query if they are open or not. The query must work across day boundaries (For example 10:00am - 01:00am).  Their hours of operation are not presently defined in the collection as of yet so I can set the schema based on the answers to this question.

But for example, let's say I have a collection like this:

```
    [
    {
      "name": "Pete's Bar",
      "hours":
              {
                "Sun": {
                  "open": "0800",
                  "close": "1800"
                },
                "Mon": {
                  "open": "0800",
                  "close": "1800"
                },
                "Tue": {
                  "open": "0800",
                  "close": "1800"
                },
                "Wed": {
                  "open": "closed",
                  "close": "closed"
                },
                "Thu": {
                  "open": "0800",
                  "close": "1800"
                },
                "Fri": {
                  "open": "0800",
                  "close": "0100"
                },
                "Sat": {
                  "open": "0800",
                  "close": "0100"
                }
              }
    }       
]
```

Based on the current time of day AND the day of week how would I query the database for all restaurants that are currently open?  I currently just find all restaurants and do the logic in python.  I would like to just have mongo do it if possible.    AGAIN!  The 'hours' schema can change to fit the answer.

Comment: Can't give the precise answer but if you're able to write a [js "stored procedure"](http://dirolf.com/2010/04/05/stored-javascript-in-mongodb-and-pymongo.html), I'd recommend converting each open and close time to `unixtime` (or 'utc'), then you could do `if open_time <= now and now <= close_time`. But you'd still need to add stuff to convert open & close times (to a chosen timestamp obj) for the various days and then check each against now_time. Again, maybe do-able via js but note that it's not equivalent to a stored procedure; just vaguely similar. And may not be query-efficient.

Comment: Additionally, `open_time` has to be created/calculated against the **current** date/time in order for that comparison to work. Worth trying but based on speed, it may not be much more efficient than your current "get from query and process in python" approach; since the query overhead will still apply for the js-proc.

Comment: Yes, I am basically doing all of that logic outside of the query.  I don't know if speed differential would be between the two methods.  Plus my python logic works now.  I'm looking for the silver bullet if it even exists :)

Answer (score 1):

After changing the data model (see the end of this post), the query below will return all restaurants that are open at the moment. You can make this query work over date boundaries by adding additional entries for a day. For example, below I have added an entry for Sunday between 00:00 and 01:00 which in fact extends the open hours on Saturday(08:00 to 24:00). There are more elegant ways to implement this, see for example the comment by @aneroid on your question.

```
var now = new Date();
var weekday =["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
var day=weekday[now.getDay()]
var hour=now.getHours()+'00'

db.openinghours.find({
        hours: {
            $elemMatch: {
                "day": day,
                "open": {
                    $lte: hour,
                    $ne: "closed"
                },
                "close": {
                    $gte: hour,
                    $ne: "closed"
                }
```

I have changed your model to this:

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Pete's Bar",
      "hours":[
         {  
            "day":"Sun",
            "open":"0000",
            "close":"0100"
         },  
         {  
            "day":"Sun",
            "open":"0800",
            "close":"1800"
         },
         {  
            "day":"Mon",
            "open":"0800",
            "close":"1800"
         },
         {  
            "day":"Tue",
            "open":"0800",
            "close":"1800"
         },
         {  
            "day":"Wed",
            "open":"closed",
            "close":"closed"
         },
         {  
            "day":"Thu",
            "open":"0800",
            "close":"1800"
         },
         {  
            "day":"Fri",
            "open":"0800",
            "close":"1800"
         },
         {  
            "day":"Sat",
            "open":"0800",
            "close":"2400"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. Will it work across day boundaries such as 1200 - 0100?

Comment: You can make it support day boundaries by adding additional entries for the next day, see my amended post. If you want to handle this more elegantly you need to convert your hours to date time values when querying.